# NER german natural objects

Tags: python, r, spacy, named-entity-recognition, sa

I have some familiarity with R, and I am just starting with python to get into NLP, with a specific interest in Semantic Analysis and Named Entity Recognition (i am currently learning spaCy).
I have a background in Humanities and very little computational knowledge.

With this in mind, I am interested in exploring sentiments in German literature of a specific period, in relation to the use and references to geographical places and natural elements of the specific area and time this literature was produced.

I thought I could use dictionaries with tagged places/natural elements in combination with dictionaries for sentiments, and proceed in R with the text mining of my corpus, by analysing how emotions are expressed in proximity (or in relation to) the entities I am interested in.

Thus two questions: do such NER dictionaries exist for geographical/natural elements, and do they exist in German? Where could I find them?

I would be very happy to read any sort of suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give examples of the geographical/natural elements?

Comment: By geographical I mean towns, cities, villages, but also rivers, lakes, mounts, hills, anything that has a proper name and/or a geographical 'label' in reality. And by natural I mean general entities such as field, lawn, pond, snow, rain, cliff, and so on

Answer (score 1):

Stanford coreNLP provides good ner tagger. You can find ner models for German also. See their wbsite https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html. Check how the predictions are coming.